# how to create mutablelistof() of many mutablelistof()?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to add mutable lists in other mutable lists
but i dont know how to do it.

I tried mutablelist of mutablelist but not working.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Before reading my answer I suggest you to read [Plus and minus operators](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/collection-plus-minus.html) and try to figure it out yourself.

If you're still having trouble understanding here are samples of the operations you can do with collections such as Lists.

**Adding multiple lists to one list:**

```
fun main() {
    val listA = mutableListOf(1, 2, 3)
    val listB = mutableListOf(3, 5, 6)
    
    val listOfLists = mutableListOf(listA, listB)
    println(listOfLists)
}
```

results in:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [3, 5, 6]]
```

**Combining multiple lists in one list:**

```
fun main() {
    val listA = mutableListOf(1, 2, 3)
    val listB = mutableListOf(3, 5, 6)
    
    val combinedLists = mutableListOf(listA + listB)
    println(combinedLists)
}
```

which results in:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 3, 5, 6]]
```

**Substracting one list from another:**

```
fun main() {
    val listA = mutableListOf(1, 2, 3)
    val listB = mutableListOf(3, 5, 6)
    
    val substractedLists = mutableListOf(listA - listB)
    println(substractedLists)
}
```

which results in:

```
[[1, 2]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a mutableList using add function as below.

```
val a = mutableListOf(1, 2)
val b = mutableListOf(2, 3)
val c = mutableListOf(a)
c.add(b)
val d : MutableList<MutableList<Int>> = mutableListOf()
d.add(a)
d.add(b)
println(d)
```